# Why does my git remote repository try to push/pull from /home/git directory?

Tags: git

I'm trying to follow these instructions but it's failing at the last step

Git global setup:

```
git config --global user.name "Swaroop"<br/>
git config --global user.email "whatever@gmail.com"
```

Create Repository

```
mkdir project-1

cd project-1

git init

touch README

git add README

git commit -m 'first commit'

git remote add origin git@git.myserver.com:uname/project-1.git

git push -u origin master
```

But it fails with

```
±  |master ✓| → git push -u origin master

fatal: '/home/git/repositories/uname/project-1.git' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

why is git looking up the local "/home/git" folder when i explicitly added the remote origin?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `/home/git` is the home directory of the git user on your git server.  Of course that all depends on how your git servers was set up.  I follow these instructions for setting up a git server http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server